# Kotlin if statement executing even when false

Tags: android, if-statement, imageview, kotlin

I'm trying to check if a profile has an image URL set and, if so, load it into an `ImageView`:

```
val hasImage = image != null && image.isNotBlank()

if (hasImage) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(row.image)
}
```

`image` is a nullable string. The problem is that even when `hasImage` is false, it still loads the image, as you can see:

[image: WHYYYYY]

However, if I do `val hasImage = false` it behaves as expected.

I'm incredibly confused as to what is going on here. Why is the `if` condition still executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably there’s a **compilation** problem. The screenshot shows an impossible scenario. Where do you start the app? Try to rebuild and then debug again. Also try to add some logs.

It’s not due to the way you chose to check the Boolean expression...

Comment: I just use Shift+F9 to start the app. I'll try rebuilding. What sort of logs are you wanting to see? (Sorry, this is day 2 of my experience with Android/Kotlin.)

Comment: Simply add a log of the Boolean and then inside the if for example :)

Comment: The rebuild seems to have done the trick! Thanks! I spent way too many hours trying to figure out why on earth it was executing.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is an empty string ("") that Boolean will be evaluated as true and the if branch executed. Change your condition accordingly and/or use this standard library function, for the sake of clarity:

```
isNullOrBlank()
```

(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html)

Like this:

```
if (!image.isNullOrBlank()) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(row.image)
}
```

Comment: Exact same issue doing it that way. I may be wrong, but I don't think it has to do with my check of the string; as you can see in the image, it says the bool is false.

Comment: Adding a log? Log.d("image", "Image is: $image") and check that the image is not null first

Comment: It's not null. If you look at the bottom right corner of the screenshot, you can see that it's "". I'll do the log, though, and see what it comes out with. *EDIT:* Confirmed, it's empty.

Comment: If it's empty then hasImage will be true. Not sure what you were expecting, I am glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Why would it be true? Unless I'm misunderstanding what `.isNotBlank()` does... Shouldn't `.isNotBlank()` return false for ""?

Comment: Sorry just a typo, I meant "will not be true" 
From the standard library (Strings.kt)

" * Returns `true` if this char sequence is not empty and contains some characters except of whitespace characters."

Which means that `"".isNotBlank()` will return `false`, as expected.

Your first `image != null` in the example is redundant. My two cents